# tslint logs 'Cannot find module' but code works fine

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

In my angular project using typescript I get the mentioned error by tslint for all my imports, while the browser doesn't throw any errors at all and behaviour is as expected.

Typescript classes look like

someClass.ts

```
export abstract class SomeClass {
    // ...
}
```

someOtherClass.controller.ts

```
import { SomeClass } from '../../someClass';

export class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Since I'm pretty new to this stuff I'm not sure which other information might be helpful, so just let me know if I left something out :)

Comment: Could you add the full text of the error output from tslint?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, unfortunately at that time our project lead decided to go with plain javascript to save time. So this particular code doesn't exist any more, therefore I cannot reproduce the error output. Anyway, thanks for your willingness to help (if that word exists :-D)!